# How to find all files with a function in phpstorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

How I can find *and* show all files in Phpstorm where this method

```
$this->other_model->any_method()
```

is called?

Comment: Find usages - alt+f7

Comment: Did you try searching for this problem before posting a question here?

Comment: You did not provide a valid method name. Which type does `$this` represent and of which type is `$this->other_model`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`cmd+shift+f` for **Mac** and `ctrl+shift+f` for **Windows** will find any piece of text throughout the project or directory. Or you could use `alt+f7` to find usages.

[PHPStorm Keyboard Mapping](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/phpstorm/docs/PhpStorm_ReferenceCard.pdf).

[Viewing Structure of a Source File](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html#d902326e52).

Comment: Please, advise me also how to find methods that there is not on model: `$this->other_model->Check if this method availabne in model` `other_model`

Comment: You can use `ctrl+space` for auto-completion when typing out the method name. If the method exists, you'll get completion suggestions.
You can also go to the **Project** tool window (somewhere at the sides) and turn on **show members** from the context menu. This will show you all the class members in the Project tool window.

Comment: ```CTRL + SHIFT + F``` works for Linux as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for symbol with combination `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N`. This combination allows you to search not only PHP classes/methods but also PHP variables, CSS classes etc.

If you want to find method usages in files:
click on your method and press `Alt+F7`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search any composition of your desire search, you can use from **searching everywhere**. I prefer to use this because **PhpStorm makes it possible to look for any item of the source code, databases, actions, elements of the user interface, etc. in a single action**. 
to use that, only press **search button in the right upper corner of phpStorm** or **2 times press shift key** on your keyboard. Now you can find your search everywhere. This is great functionality of phpStorm. 
To read more information about using this search method, go to the following link:
[Searching Everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/searching-everywhere.html/)

To See all the methods for search in phpStorm, Go to the following link:[Searching Through the Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/searching-through-the-source-code.html)